# Specified cast is not valid - bigint to long - C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am trying to map bigint data from sq server table to c# long variable. Which I believe is the correct way to map.

```
long id = (long)ds.Tables[2].Rows[0].ItemArray[0];
```

I also tried below as suggested on SO.

```
long id = (long)(double)ds.Tables[2].Rows[0].ItemArray[0];
```

With both above I get below error:

```
System.InvalidCaseException : Specified cast is not valid.
```

In case you are wondering what data it contains, it is "1".

Comment: Try calling GetType() on the object to see the type

Comment: Yeah i suspect the column your looking at isnt what you think it is

Comment: @TheGeneral When I debug Rows, it has correct data.

Comment: Have you tried Convert.ToLong

Comment: @JonasH are you suggesting to call GetType on ItemArray?

Comment: We beleive you that it has the correct data, it is just not the type you expect. what does `ds.Tables[2].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].GetType()` return?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Oops. Its Int32. But In db table type is BigInt.

Comment: So yes, Bigintg to Long is not a valid cast. Now why does it havea BigInt type? Not this question - more debugging and possibly a new question.

Comment: There is an implicit cast from int to long, so an explicit cast must also be valid (though redundant). I suspect you are looking at the wrong column. Please include the select statement that is used to fill this dataset.

Comment: @ZoharPeled DataTable has only one row and column. so there is no question of looking at wrong db. I see that it is int type. But I need to convert it to long.

Comment: @ZoharPeled a explicit cast does not work if the int is boxed in a object. https://dotnetfiddle.net/Evwxvv line 9 works, line 10 fails.

Comment: Convert.toInt64 got it worked. Thanks all.

Comment: @TomTom [Sql Server BigInt is an Int64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings) - that's exactly [what c# long is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/long)...

Comment: But SQL Serer biging has no cast to long defined. It does not amtter what it IS. Casts are totally handled by defining them, not by the data.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain you are correct, of course. you can only unbox to the underlying type directly - so `int a = 5; object b = a; long c = (long)(int)b; long d = (long)a;` - c will compile, d will not.

Comment: int64 is for bigint

Answer (score 5):

> Convert.toInt64 got it worked. Thanks all

You are just hiding a bigger problem you have. The datatype in your column of your c# DataTable object held within the DataSet `ds` is likely set incorrectly. You need to set your table up so that the column's property for [DataType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.datatype?view=netframework-4.7.2) is set to be `Int64`.

Comment: What do you mean by setting table up? Are you saying I need to change data type in sql table?

Comment: No, you need to configure the data table to treat the column as Int64. Try storing a number greater than 2^32 in the DB and you will get an error with your current setup